# Explain the Cayley data format

Tags: graph-databases

Where can I find a reference of the Cayley database format? I find it confusing.

For example in the demo database of movie info, why do so many values start with "/en"?

Why does the following row have '/film' twice and why is there a dot at the end?

```
":/en/the_window" "/film/film/starring" ":53570" .
```

Why does Stephen Fry appear so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example cayley's database of movies is part of [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/film), so is using the freebase name convention.

The id property follow the rule:

> /en - top level namespace for all human readable IDs

In the case of `film/film/starring` the first film is a common domain, the second one is the object and the third one is the name of the property.

You can read more at the page [namespace in freebase wiki](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Namespace)